# Extracting class within class in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract customer service star rating from the three reviews in the html:

[image]

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
oururl= urllib.request.urlopen(x).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(oururl,'lxml') 
for rating in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rating-customer-service"}):
    list_rating.append(rating.find_all("div",{"class":"star-rating"}))
```

But I do not get the star ratings in the list_rating. Can anyone suggest alternate approaches?

Comment: Can you add your html as code, and please add more detail about what your code can do now, does it makes any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
oururl= urllib.request.urlopen(x).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(oururl,'lxml') 
for rating in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"star-rating"}):
    list_rating.append(rating.span.text)
```